# Cannot install Kivy (windows 10, python 3.8)

Tags: python, pip, kivy, installation

I am having a great deal of trouble installing kivy on my system. I have had this working before but for some reason am having an extremely hard time right now.
I follow the directions verbatim, setting up a virtualenv, activating the env, installing the dependencies (docutils, pygments, pypiwin32, kivy_deps.sdl2==0.1*., kivy_deps.glew==0.1*., kivy_deps.gstreamer==0.1.*).

all of that part above works fine. when i finally go to install kivy (py -m pip install kivy), i get a barrage of errors:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\ferna\Documents\Python\pyenv3864\Scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ferna\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ctrp6hf9\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ferna\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ctrp6hf9\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info 
--egg-base 'C:\Users\ferna\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ctrp6hf9\kivy\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\ferna\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ctrp6hf9\kivy\
    Complete output (79 lines):
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
       File "C:\Users\ferna\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ctrp6hf9\kivy\setup.py", line 1073, in <module>
         setup(
       File "C:\Users\ferna\Documents\Python\pyenv3864\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
         _install_setup_requires(attrs)
       File "C:\Users\ferna\Documents\Python\pyenv3864\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires    
         dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
       File "C:\Users\ferna\Documents\Python\pyenv3864\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 716, in fetch_build_eggs
         resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
       File "C:\Users\ferna\Documents\Python\pyenv3864\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
         dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
       File "C:\Users\ferna\Documents\Python\pyenv3864\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
         return self.obtain(req, installer)
       File "C:\Users\ferna\Documents\Python\pyenv3864\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
         return installer(requirement)
       File "C:\Users\ferna\Documents\Python\pyenv3864\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 786, in fetch_build_egg
         return cmd.easy_install(req)
       File "C:\Users\ferna\Documents\Python\pyenv3864\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 665, in easy_install   
         dist = self.package_index.fetch_distribution(
       File "C:\Users\ferna\Documents\Python\pyenv3864\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 655, in fetch_distribution    
         dist = find(requirement)
       File "C:\Users\ferna\Documents\Python\pyenv3864\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 635, in find
         loc = self.download(dist.location, tmpdir)
       File "C:\Users\ferna\Documents\Python\pyenv3864\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 579, in download
         found = self._download_url(scheme.group(1), spec, tmpdir)   
       File "C:\Users\ferna\Documents\Python\pyenv3864\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 824, in _download_url
         return self._attempt_download(url, filename)
       File "C:\Users\ferna\Documents\Python\pyenv3864\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 830, in _attempt_download     
         headers = self._download_to(url, filename)
       File "C:\Users\ferna\Documents\Python\pyenv3864\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 745, in _download_to
         block = fp.read(bs)
       File "C:\Users\ferna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 454, in read
         n = self.readinto(b)
       File "C:\Users\ferna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\http\client.py", line 498, in readinto
         n = self.fp.readinto(b)
       File "C:\Users\ferna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
         return self._sock.recv_into(b)
       File "C:\Users\ferna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
         return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
       File "C:\Users\ferna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ssl.py", line 1099, in read
         return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
     socket.timeout: The read operation timed out
    Using setuptools
    User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
    Using this graphics system: OpenGL
    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)

    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

    ERROR: Dependency for context.pyx not resolved: config.pxi       
    ERROR: Dependency for compiler.pyx not resolved: config.pxi      
    ERROR: Dependency for context_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for fbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for gl_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi  
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi        
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl_utils.pyx not resolved: config.pxi  
    ERROR: Dependency for shader.pyx not resolved: config.pxi        
    ERROR: Dependency for stencil_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for scissor_instructions.pyx not resolved: conf    ERROR: Dependency for vertex_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi                                              xi       
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi  
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_mock.pyx not resolved: config.i        pxi                                                         ed: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_gl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_glew.pyx not resolved: config.pxi      pxi                                                         i        
    ERROR: Dependency for cgl_sdl2.pyx not resolved: config.pxi      pxi                                                         pxi      
    ERROR: Dependency for svg.pyx not resolved: config.pxi  
    ----------------------------------------                         fo Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_inpy egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have also tried using the nightly backups, installing the wheel, trying tar.gz; but I'm pretty confused here.

Comment: I think Kivy does not yet support Python 3.8. Its PyPI project page https://pypi.org/project/Kivy/ and its Windows installation instructions https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html both say not.

Comment: -__- what an oversight. -so when a package is marked "cp38" does that not imply its compatibility with python 3.8? i guess the nomenclature led me to believe 3.8 was stable https://kivy.org/downloads/appveyor/kivy/

Comment: I'm no Kivy expert so I can't say anything about nomenclature. But your question said *it used to work* and that rang the upgrade alarm in my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't currently provide wheels for the latest Kivy stable release under Python 3.8 on Windows. Your options are:

- set up a working compiler toolchain and compile Kivy yourself
- use Python 3.7
- use the Kivy master branch, which does have Python 3.8 wheels available - I don't remember how but at worst someone on the Kivy discord will know

Note that the latest Kivy stable release *does* support Python 3.8, it works fine and that's why the first option is available. The problem is entirely the lack of prebuilt binaries.

Answer (score 0):

`easy_install kivy` works (but easy_install is deprecated, so beware)